# C sha1 implementation not working on Unix

Tags: c, windows, unix, sha

I'm using [this implementation](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/src/sha1.c.txt) of SHA1 in C. Works fine on Windows but it does not output correct hashes on Unix (tried it on Ubuntu and Mac OS 10.8). Furthermore, on Ubuntu it outputs different hash from the same message.

I guess I could use another implementation, just curious why that happens.

**EDIT**

Thanks, you guys are right. Changed it to

```
typedef unsigned int UINT4;
```

seems to work fine.

Comment: Compile it with maximum warnings enabled, and see if the compiler finds any of the code suspicious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are these 64bit unix'es?

```
/* UINT4 defines a four byte word */
typedef unsigned long int UINT4;
```

will actually be 8 bytes on 64 bit Linux (but 4 bytes on 64 bit Windows)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Answer (score 2):

If any of the platforms is 64-bit and has a 64-bit `unsigned long`, this code might have issues:

```
/* UINT4 defines a four byte word */
typedef unsigned long int UINT4;
```

Didn't read the code closely enough to see if the way `UINT4` is used would break if it's actually 8 bytes, but it sounds fishy.

Answer (score 1):

> typedef unsigned long int UINT4;

Maybe your Unix implementation uses 64-bit unsigned longs.

Try

```
#include <stdint.h>

/* ... */

typedef uint32_t UINT4;
```

and use a C99 compiler.